# are Virgo tools actively maintained?

Tags: eclipse-virgo, wab

Virgo tools limits the maximum Dynamic Web Module version of Web Application Bundles to the old 2.5

It seems that my Virgo server version (3.6.2) is using Tomcat 7, that is able to manage more recent servlet specifications (I need 3.0)

I'm beginning to think that Virgo tool are not as actively mantained as Virgo server is. In fact, tools documentation talks about Juno and Indigo releases and Kepler is going to be replaced in 5 days as stable release

Are Virgo tools a commonly used way to develop against the Virgo server in eclipse?

Are they been slowly forgotten by users/developers?

Answer (score 0):

With the Eclipse Kepler release (June 26, 2013), 4 projects were removed. Virgo was one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this post - for anyone still interested, a quick update: Yes, the Virgo Tools are still actively developed. We are using them since 2014 and are using them in Eclipse Mars --> Neon --> Oxygen.

The tooling is working really well in our case, we have also set up a fork for extending the tooling to better support our development. If you are interested, have a look at:
https://github.com/esd-ches/virgo-tools